# How do I deal with off-topic posts in Triage?

Tags: support, review-queues, scope, triage, migration

I just got an off-topic post in Triage. The question was fine, however it really should have been moved to another site.

How do I react in this situation? The question is not OK, however editing it would not fix it and closing would be a bit heavy-handed.

Comment: Why is closing an off-topic question heavy handed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Choose <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> > "should be closed..." > "off-topic because ..." > "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network".

If it the site is not in that list and you're *really* sure it should be moved there, choose <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> > "in need of moderator intervention" (thanks @gparyani) and explain where it should be moved to and why.

Unsalvageable does not necessarily mean "it's a bad question", just that it needs to be closed. Also, please [don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225006/295232).

Comment: Unsalvageable means that it's not salvageable by having a community member edit it (i.e. someone other than the OP). It *doesn't* mean that the question won't *ever* be a good fit for SO. It means that the question *as it is now, or how it could be when edited by a community member* is not a good fit for SO. The fact that people believe that "Unsalvageable" requires the higher bar of the question not *ever* being a good fit for SO is one of the major problems with Triage. That belief results in a large number of questions wrongly going into the H&I queue and not getting the CV/CF they should.

Comment: It should also be said that one should only use "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" for *good* questions which are known to be on-topic on another site. It should not be used for bad questions which will just get closed on the other site. Knowing this requires familiarity with the requirements of the other site. Migrating bad questions just results in the question being closed on the other site, kicking the question back to SO.

Comment: @Makyen thanks. I wrote the answer yesterday just before sleeping, it wasn't complete.