# Triage → Unsalvageable → Should be closed… has been closed?

Tags: bug, triage, user-interface

I encountered https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20584044 which contains an off-topic question.

I attempted to follow the advice in [How do I deal with off-topic posts in Triage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360469/1115360):

> Choose Unsalvageable > "should be closed…" > "off-topic because …" > "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network".

But when I click the "Unsalvageable" button there is no "should be closed…" option in the resulting dialog:

[image]

Has that option been intentionally removed since the advice was given back in December?

(Yes, I went to the question and voted to close it.)

*A little while later…* I am seeing the option (and the "Duplicate" option) on other reviews. What sort of glitch could have caused the problem?

Comment: This review is now completed, so I can't reproduce. On other Triage questions, though, I see the "Should be closed" as normal.

Comment: Currently the "Should be closed" options are missing for me as well (because it's already closed). So maybe there's a bug where the system thought the question was already closed?

Comment: AFAIK, it should invalidate the task if it was closed outside the queue.

Comment: @Braiam as the OP said _"I went to the question and voted to close it"_, I don't think the question was closed at the point that the OP was having this issue.

Comment: @TinyGiant You are correct. I am pretty sure that there were no close votes on it at that point.